# Learning Python: Find and Add value inside file

Tags: python

I want to find last value (ie. `lo:`) and just append a value to this.
ie.
 i want to find the `lo:3`, in this case my last value and append a `lo:4`

File:

```
ifconfig lo:1
 address x.x.x.x
 netmask x.x.x.x
 gateway x.x.x.x

ifconfig lo:2
 address x.x.x.x
 netmask x.x.x.x
 gateway x.x.x.x

ifconfig lo:3
 address x.x.x.x
 netmask x.x.x.x
 gateway x.x.x.x
```

What is the best way to do ? Split or Loop + Readline with check.

Comment: Add some code you've written to tackle this or I'd feel like doing your work. What is the problem you have?

Comment: is the format of the file known in advance? you have always 3 lines after ifconfing lo: ?

Comment: Jochen, i could add my code, but i just want to know the function, or call or whatever. Then i will do my research. I want to learn. By the way, my goal is do the following:
Check my last "lo:VALUE", then add new "lo:VALUE+1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Without assuming too much on the structure of the file**, you have to parse the file and take track of every "ifconfig lo:" line, e.g updating a running maximum. In this case:

```
max_value_observed  == 3 # at the end of this step
```

Once you have seen it all, you will know the maximum value and will be able to compute the next:

```
new_max_value = max_value_observed + 1
```

and now you are ready to append the data to your file.
Obviously, if the file has more known in advance structure it's easier (eg you know that the file is sorted: you don't need to compute the maximum but it simply suffices to find the last value).

Comment: you've got the point ! I think i have to build a if searching the string inside the file. What do you think ?

Comment: @Simão: you can use a simple approach (something like if line.startswith("ifconfig lo:" and then capturing the value) or an (equally simple) regex. IT depends on the degree or robustness you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

There's a number of ways to do this. One of them involves using regular expressions, e.g.:

```
import re
print max(map(int, re.findall('ifconfig[ \t]+lo:(\d+)', open('f.txt').read(), re.M)))
```

Figuring out how it works is left as an exercise.